# Fix application deploy error on AzureDevops

Tags: azure, iis, azure-devops

I have created release in Azure Devops, which should be deplyoing my web application to IIS which is on a physical server (Windows Server 2008) but firstly I am getting a warning:

> ##[Warning 1]
> The operating system the agent is running on is "Windows Server" (OS name: 2008, OS version: 7601), which will not be supported by the .NET 6 based v3 agent. Please upgrade the operating system of this host to ensure compatibility with the v3 agent. See https://aka.ms/azdo-pipeline-agent-version

Then I am getting a error: [image]

I have created an Agent on my server, and until today I was not getting this error. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 reached end of life years ago, so no modern tool is going to support it any more.

You might feel lucky that things were running, but that luck finally ran out. You have to upgrade your machine to a supported Windows version.